# UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities to exclude 16GB 5th generation iPod touch without rear camera?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, ipod

I'm working on a camera app which requires a rear camera.

In May 2013 Apple released the 16GB 5th generation iPod touch, which doesn't have a rear camera.

What can I set my `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` values to, to ensure that the app can't be installed on the 16GB 5th gen iPod?

[Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3) mentions the `still-camera` and `video-camera` required device capabilities, but these indicate "the presence of a camera [with video capabilities] on the device". The 16GB 5th gen iPod does have a front-facing camera, so are `still-camera` and `video-camera` still true for that iPod? There is a `front-facing-camera` capability, but nothing specifically for a rear facing camera.

I found this [table of capabilities](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/10/30/uirequireddevicecapabilities-and-device-compatibility-matrix), but it is from October last year and so doesn't list the 16GB 5th gen iPod.

Thanks.

Comment: Curious - why would a camera app require only a rear camera? Why not support any camera?

Comment: I can't really say because I'm under NDA with the people I'm working for :| The app's functionality does work with the front camera, but it's better with the rear camera, so I think 16GB 5th gen iPod owners who downloaded the app would be disappointed.

Answer (score 0):

"The 16GB 5th gen iPod does have a front-facing camera, so are still-camera and video-camera still true for that iPod? "

It is an `still-camera` and `video-camera` like the previous generation's front facing.

It only have:

"Tap to control exposure for video or stills"

While the bigger, colorful models have:

"Autofocus and
Tap to focus video or still images"

[Source](http://www.apple.com/ipod-touch/specs.html)